# How to make MUI Table with sticky header AND sticky column?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to do MUI table which will have sticky headers when scrolling verticaly and also sticky first column when scrolling horizontally, but keep getting results as in demo:

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-table-sticky-column-demo-forked-4f0t4k?file=/demo.tsx).

I triead many styles but keep getting stuck with it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sticky column you can create another style `stickyHeader`, add `zIndex` property and set to tablecell

```
stickyHeader: {
   position: "sticky",
   left: 0,
   background: "white",
   boxShadow: "5px 2px 5px grey",
   borderRight: "2px solid black",
   zIndex: "9999 !important"
}

<TableCell className={classes.stickyHeader}>
      Dessert (100g serving)
</TableCell>
```

Also add `maxHeight` in `TableContainer` style for scrolling as added in [mui table example](https://v4.mui.com/components/tables/#StickyHeadTable.js).

```
<TableContainer style={{ maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 200, border: "1px solid black" }}>
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-table-sticky-column-demo-forked-hw658l)